# how to tell maven assembly on a submodule to include only dependencies this module needs?

Tags: maven, dependencies, maven-assembly-plugin, multi-module

I am working on a multi-module maven project with these modules

```
parent
  |-- restful    // this is a jersey restful service as a WAR
  |-- shared     // some stuff shared by all other modules as a jar
  |-- cl-client  // a commandline client to the restful service, needs assembly
```

The parent pom.xml uses dependencyManagement to list all dependencies used by all modules

The pom for cl-client includes the assembly plugin, configured to be executed at the package phase:

```xml
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>distro-assembly</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <descriptors>
              <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
            </descriptors>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```

and the assembly.xml is as follows:

```xml
<assembly>
  <id>commandlinable</id>
  <formats>
    <format>dir</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <moduleSets>
    <moduleSet>
      <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>
      <includes>
        <include>my:cl-client</include>
      </includes>
      <binaries>
        <outputDirectory>${artifactId}</outputDirectory>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
        <dependencySets>
          <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>${artifactId}/lib</outputDirectory>
            <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
          </dependencySet>
        </dependencySets>
      </binaries>
    </moduleSet>
  </moduleSets>
</assembly>
```

When I run `mvn package`, the cl-client modules assembles fine and does create the directory that I hoped for, but the only problem is that all dependencies jars are copied in the lib/ directory, even the ones that are only used by the "restful" module such as jersey related jars.  I tried to flip the `useProjectArtifact` flag, but it didn't seem to make any difference.

So I am just wondering if there is anyway I can tell Maven assembly to include only the jars required by the cl-client module.  I poured through quite a few online resources on Maven assembly on multi-module projects, but wasn't able to get any clear answers.

Comment: Does the cl-client project have the restful project as a dependency? If so, presumably executing `mvn dependency:tree` on the cl-client project shows all the JARs you are seeing in your assembly output?

Comment: Does the `cl-client` pom inherit from parent pom?

Comment: @Andrew yes, the cl-client pom inherits from parent pom

Comment: @Duncan  thank you very much for the suggestion. I am still quite new to maven and didn't know about the dependency:tree command.  This is very useful.  It appears that hbase jar has a dependency on jersey, so that is why it is included.

Comment: @Duncan: Would you (or Jim) please add an answer to this question with the solution. Then select this anweser as correct please Jim. It will then no longer be marked as "unanswered" -thanks!

Comment: @Jan Good point, done.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `mvn dependency:tree` command to understand which dependencies exist between your modules. You'll probably discover an artifact has a transitive dependency on jersey, which is why it's being included.

Comment: +1: Fast one (aside from being a good answer as well, of course ;-)